# Impdp ora-00904 invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, impdp

I'm triying to import our database which is in `WE8MSWIN1252` instance to a new `AL32UTF8` instance.
I'm using `impdp` tool to achieve this.
I get the following error

> Processing object type
>   SCHEMA_EXPORT/PACKAGE/COMPILE_PACKAGE/PACKAGE_SPEC/ALTER_PACKAGE_SPEC
>   ORA-39083: Object type ALTER_PACKAGE_SPEC:"MyOwner"."MyPackageOwner"
>   failed to create with error: ORA-00904: "DECL_OBJ#": invalid
>   identifier

Please note that when I compile this package using `SQLplus` it is working as expected
Do you have any idea about what can causes this error ?
Thanks,
Bilel

Comment: [Possibly related](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2476156_1.html)? The fix anyway (which you need a support contract to see), if not the exact scenario... So you might need to raise an SR with Oracle to confirm and get detailed advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just excluded views, packages and package_compile from the export and this worked as expected.

Answer (score 7):

Open SQL Developer. Set the PLScope identifiers parameter (Tools > Preferences > Database > PL/SQL Compiler > PLScope identifiers) from All to None.
Close and open the SQL Developer.

It solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

In the support note mentioned above, Oracle says that this error is related to SQL Developer and a specific patched version of Oracle DB (12.2.0.1.181016).

As a workaround it seems you can disable PL/Scope (a functionality to parse and analyse PL/SQL code) like this :

- Open SQL Developer Set the PLScope identifiers parameter (Tools > Preferences > Database > PL/SQL Compiler > PLScope identifiers) from All to None.
- Close and open the SQL Developer

Comment: I'm not using Sql developer, I'm using datadump tool.

Comment: The support note explicitly says that is not really an SQL Developer issue, but does offer a workaround (which you should not be reproducing, pretty sure that breaks your support contract terms...) if you experience it from within SQL Developer. But it looks like the underlying problem *might* also be what's affecting `impdp` here. So the actual fix (not workaround) there *might* work for this scenario too, but the OP really needs to ask Oracle (via a service request).

Comment: right, but as impdp can be run from SQL Developer it might have been the case, thanks Alex for adding clarification.